# Twilio conference participant does not return "no-answer" call status

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

In my Java application I make a call via Twilio to person A. Once they answer I create a conference:

```
                Dial.Builder dial = new Dial.Builder()
                        .action(actionUrl)
                        .timeout(timeout)
                        .callerId(callBackNumber);

                Conference conference = new Conference.Builder("MyConference")
                        .statusCallback(statusCallbackUrl)
                        .statusCallbackEvents(Arrays.asList(Conference.ConferenceEvent.values()))
                        .build();
                dial = dial.conference(conference);
                return new VoiceResponse.Builder().dial(dial.build());
```

Then, when event with conferenceSid comes from Twilio I call person B to add them as participant:

```
                Participant participant = Participant.creator(
                        conferenceSid,
                        new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(fromPhoneNumber),
                        new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(toPhoneNumber))
                        .setStatusCallback(statusCallbackUrl)
                        .setStatusCallbackEvent(Arrays.asList("initiated ringing answered completed".split(" ")))
                        .setRecord(true)
                        .create();
```

The problem is that when person B does not answer the call, I don't get "no-answer" as CallStatus when Twilio sends request to my statusCallbackUrl. It's only "completed" status I get at the end. I get "no-answer" status only if I dial person B via Number noun, without conference (but I need conference call). Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Any help and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the person being called doesn't answer, but their voicemail does? To Twilio, an answered call is an answered call, regardless of whether it's a person or a machine, and that might trigger the call being recorded as a complete call. Alternatively, if you really want to dig into this, I recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and providing CallSids where this happened.

Comment: I tested this scenario with the same callee phone - when I called via Number noun I got "no-answer" call status as it should be, but conference participant call in the same conditions returned only "completed" status. Yes, I probably try to contact Twilio support.